# Cartoon MC: 2 boy and 1 girl fight evil

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, cartoon

The cartoon I watched was multiple episodes in 2006~2015 on "Cartoon network" (Don't remember the exact timeline).  The main thing I remember is that the main characters are two boys and one girl  (around 10-12 years old). The two boys had something like ancient China's ki. The girl can control water. They are in the same sect fighting an evil sect.

I also remember a particular episode:

- The three main characters fight in some cave and the girl get split away from the other two and gets captured by the evil sect. The two boys get lost and find something like an clock made of gold and go to the future. In the future, they see they had mastered their ki and were fighting the girl who had joined the evil sect because she had been left alone in that cave. With the help of their future selves, they get back to the cave and save the girl in time. But when all three go back to the clock, it had dissapeared.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the animation style?  You should check out the [other suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) for anime-id questions.

Comment: Definitely not from Japan. It somewhat similar to `Kim Possible` cartoon's style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Shaolin Wuzang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaolin_Wuzang) (2007).

> Meanwhile, Master Sanzang consults the spirits of the ancient Grand
>   Masters of Shaolin. They tell him to seek out the spirits of the three
>   Original Shaolin Knights who defeated Heihu. The three have been
>   reincarnated into three young children, and so Master Sanzang must
>   find them and train them, in order to defeat the Demon before he can
>   find the second book.

The episode you're describing is S01E09: [*The Wheel of Time*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4613490/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

> Hua is convinced that these caves hide the legendary Wheel of Time, a
>   magical portal that allows (as its name indicates) time travel. The
>   boys however are tired and decide to go back to Shaolin. As for Hua,
>   she would rather keep on looking.

Comment: yes I re-watch it yesterday. It is like what I remember. Thank you so much.